# Feature importance with 0 score

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, feature-selection, feature-importances

[image]

I have feature importance score that showed like this picture. Why some of my features have 0 feature importance score (default, job_admin, education, job_enterpreneur, job_management, job_others, job_services, job_technician, marital_divorced, poutcome_failure, poutcome_other). Why is that happening? I'm using adaboost algorithm. Is it because there is max_features hyperparameter (because adaboost based on decision tree) that control how many features that will use for making the decision, so it makes some features that not used for making the decision get 0 score? Or is it because that feature actually USED for making the decision but have 0 importances score?

```
# get importance
importance = tuned_adaboost.best_estimator_._final_estimator.feature_importances_
importance=np.sort(importance)[::-1]
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: {}, Score: {}'.format(i,v))
```

Code Result:

```
Feature: 0, Score: 0.38
Feature: 1, Score: 0.11
Feature: 2, Score: 0.1
Feature: 3, Score: 0.09
Feature: 4, Score: 0.08
Feature: 5, Score: 0.07
Feature: 6, Score: 0.07
Feature: 7, Score: 0.06
Feature: 8, Score: 0.03
Feature: 9, Score: 0.01
Feature: 10, Score: 0.0
Feature: 11, Score: 0.0
Feature: 12, Score: 0.0
Feature: 13, Score: 0.0
Feature: 14, Score: 0.0
Feature: 15, Score: 0.0
Feature: 16, Score: 0.0
Feature: 17, Score: 0.0
Feature: 18, Score: 0.0
Feature: 19, Score: 0.0
Feature: 20, Score: 0.0
```

Comment: Before getting into the hyperparameters, I'd go back and look at the data. Are `marital`,`poutcome`, and  `job` categorical features that have been one-hot encoded? Visualize these distributions as bar plots colored by the target variable and see how they compare. Check the same for `default` and`education`.

Comment: It's possible that a feature has absolutely no impact on the target, i.e. knowing the value of the feature doesn't help knowing the target at all. For example knowing the weather on a particular day doesn't help knowing the job of a person.